# Objective-C PFQuery for string contained in an array?

Tags: objective-c, database, parse-platform

I have a Parse table that contains a "UserIDs" column, which is an array of Strings.

I want to query this table for any Row which contains a certain specified UserID in the userIDs column.

For example, let there be a row that contains "0zll0s7Faz", "x62ks620", ..., "x2jdo322" in this column, how can I get this row with a PFQuery.

So far, I have a PFQuery as follows:

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Albums"];
NSString *ide = [PFUser currentUser].objectId;

[query whereKey:@"UserIDs" containsString:ide];
```

Alternatively, I have used

```
[query whereKey:@"UserIDs" equalTo:ide];
```

Is it possible to do this as simply as I want it, or what can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereKey:equalTo:` tests equality on a singular column, but it also tests membership on an array column, so...

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Albums"];
NSString *ide = [PFUser currentUser].objectId;
[query whereKey:@"UserIDs" equalTo:ide];
```

Comment: not sure why it didn't work before, now it does. annoying, but it works now, so that is good! Thanks!